# Returning the index in a list from a search hit

Tags: python

I'm using a list of names (`cust_name`) to find if any names in the list are found in any email files located within a folder. I would like to then take the name that the search hit on and create a folder with their id `cust_id` as the folder name and copy the email file into the new folder. I have the search working, but I can't figure out how to know which index the search hit on in `cust_name` so I can use the same index position in `cust_id` to name the new folder. Here's the code:

```
for root,dirs,file in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    for cur_file in file:
        with open(cur_file, "r") as f:
            content = f.readlines()
                for line in content:
                    line = line.lower()
                    if any(word in line for word in cust_name):
                     #grab index position with search hit in cust_name
                     #grab same index position with search hit in cust_id
                     #create new folder and copy email file
```

I already know how I'm going to create the folder and copy the file. My problem is grabbing that index position.

Whenever I try to use *word* to grab the index position, I get the error that word was not defined and searching around hasn't given me any other leads on how to get the index position. Anyone out there have any tips or have done this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use enumeration as dhdavvie suggests if you just want the index. For your use case, you can also consider first [zipping](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) the cust_id and cust_name and arrays:

```
cust_tuples = zip(cust_id, cust_name)

for root, dirs, file in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    for cur_file in file:
        with open(cur_file, "r") as f:
            content = f.readlines()
            for line in content:
                line = line.lower()
                for cust_id, cust_name in cust_tuples:
                    if cust_name in line:
                        # do things with cust_id
                        break  # if you only want the first hit
```

Comment: I haven't seen the zip function before this. Thanks for pointing it out! I'll be using it more often now that I have a feel for it.

Comment: It definitely comes in handy! Glad to help :)

Comment: What's called `file` is actually a list of file_s_. Naming it singular is a bit confusing.

Comment: I kept OP's original code and only modified the necessary lines.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean this?

```
for index, line in enumerate(content):
```

Comment: Yep. I feel silly for not thinking of a simple line like this, thanks! I decided to use Karin's use of the zip function in my code, which is why I marked it as the solution.